# Android - change layout children in onMeasure

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-custom-view

is there a way how to change children of my custom view in it's onmeasure (or onlayout, ondraw, I actually dont know where to put that:)

I have this code which should shrink textview contained in my custom layout inherited from LinearLayout and add an onclicklistener to it..the problem is, this just dow not work at all..the code executes, but with no apparent effect. I also tried to call invalidate on basically all views in the tree:)

The cardContent is TextView attached to overridden LinearLayout..
I somehow feel this is all the way wrong, so please help me. I dont know much about writing custom layouts on Android..Thanks!

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if(cardContent.getLineCount() > 10){
        this.setOnClickListener(this);
        expandIcon.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        cardContent.setMaxLines(6);

        expanded = false;
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);


}
```

Comment: Which part does not work ?`this.setOnClickListener(this)` Can't you set the listener already in the constructor of your custom class?

Comment: No...The setMaxLines is not called.. Thats My maín problem..

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)` before you call
`TextView.getLineCount()`. Otherwise it always returns 0.